# How could I feature check file downloads in a browser

Tags: javascript, modernizr, browser-feature-detection

## Objective

Remove the display of a download button if the browser does not support downloading files.

## Context

I've got this [page](http://www.hillsong.co.uk/podcasts/) that enables the functionality of playing and/or downloading a podcast. The page works perfectly except when on iOS devices I don't want to display the download button because it either does not work properly or is redundant because tapping it wouldn't allow you to download anyway.

The whole site has been designed with feature testing and has [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) in it's core. How could I use feature testing to remove the download button on browsers/operating systems that don't allow download?

Last resort is to hide using `if (isiPad || isiPhone)`.